# PHP using a dll with COM + dotnet

Tags: c#, php, .net, dll, com

I have to connect to a proprietary service using a closed source `dll`. The `dll` is a `com` object, but requires **.NET 5.0**.

Is there any way I can make this work with **PHP**?

I managed to load the `dll` using PHP's COM, and I can create an instance of an object from the `dll`, then call a login method on it. I get this error message:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file..."
```

I assume this is the `.NET` dependency the `dll` is trying to use.

PHP has a dotnet functionality, but it can't load the `dll` because it's not a .NET object...

Comment: The general answer to "can I make it work with PHP" is yes, but details, deployment, etc. are important. "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0..." is about .NET Framework, not .NET Core. Doesn't look like the COM dll is .NET 5.